# Avoid repeated .click() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery script that triggers a click based on scroll position. I want to be able to click this element again if the user returns to the top of the page so the contact form will hide itself. Problem is that it creates a loop.

```
    jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (y > 400) {
        $("#contactable-inner").click();
        $("#contactable-inner").unbind('click');}
    });
```

You can go here to see what I am working on: http://algk.me

UPDATE:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var y = $("body").scrollTop();
        var hidden = $('.hidden');
        if (y >= 1000 && (hidden.hasClass('visible'))){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
        } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
        }
  });
```

Any idea how I could get this to work on scroll?

Comment: If I change the code to say:

   `jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();
      if (y > 400) {
      $("#contactable-inner").click();
      });`
It clicks because I assume the scroll position is creating several click actions at once.. and then it clicks until its finished.. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you used jQuery's [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)? Instead of simulating a click.

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
      $("#contactable").show();
    }
    else {
      $("#contactable").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is that the contact form uses toggle to show the contents within that div...

Comment: This would be perfect if It didn't use toggle to load the contents of the div.. I gotta figure out a different way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the click handler to be executed only once, then you can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/), which will make your handler to be handled only once.

```
$("#contactable-inner").one('click', function(e){
    // code goes here
});

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 400) {
        $("#contactable-inner").click();
    }
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/vEpGT/)

Comment: I added this, and I am not sure if its correct. You can see the real results on algk.me

Comment: Still tries to open and close the side area several times and then stops suddenly.

Comment: Im trying to use something like this: 

` $(window).scroll(function(){
         var y = $("body").scrollTop();
         var hidden = $('.hidden');
         if (y >= 1000 && (hidden.hasClass('visible'))){
         hidden.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
      } else {
         hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
      }
      });`